# Corrupt ROM file at CyanogenMod server

Tags: cyanogenmod, custom-roms, samsung-galaxy-note

I am trying to install CyanogenMod in my N7000 issue is the file I am downloading `cm-10.1.3-n7000.zip` from [here](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?type=stable&device=n7000) seems to be corrupted as when I try to install it from sdcard through `install zip from sdcard.` it gives me similar unable to read error. `cant open cm-10.1.3-n7000.zip (bad)`

Plus I also tried extracting it manually on my PC same happens and the zip seems to be corrected I have tried downloading couple of time using download managers but still no changes.

Is there any other link/server from where I can get the latest ROM for my phone or any other ways to solve the issues?

Comment: This could easily be a permission issue. Does the md5 check correctly? You can download an md5 checker and compare it to that string of numbers on the cyanogen site. If your download is good the numbers will match. Edit: Which recovery are you using?

Comment: I am following (this) tutorial [http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_n7000] so i am probably using Heimdall recovery.

Comment: Is the ROM on your external or internal storage? Sounds like it needs to be on the root of your internal. I've had this issue before with CWM, and just had to move the ROM. Hopefully it's that simple.

Comment: i copied it through `adb push cm-10.1.3-n7000.zip /sdcard/` this commands, i think thats the root?

Comment: Can you mount the USB storage? If you can get to it with your PC, try moving the ROM to your internal storage and trying again.

Comment: If you're following that tutorial, then you're using ClockWorkMod Recovery. Heimdall is the software you're using to install CWM. =)

Comment: well it was the corrupt file, downloaded the other version, repeated the process and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 2):

Head over to http://get.cm/?device=n7000 and note the MD5sum of the download (take care that build name / date match, of course).

You can then check it on your phone against what was downloaded using [FileSums](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cybikbase.filesums) together with any [File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.openintents.filemanager) app (filesums acts as possible target for the "send to" share button when you long press the .zip file). Open the file explorer, navigate to

```
/storage/emulated/legacy/cmupdater/
```

and then long press the file you want to calculate the MD5sum to "send  it to" filesums.

Or you can download it from your phone using your computer (via MTP or a SD card reader in case your phone has a removable one). Then check the file's MD5sum locally using the commandline tool md5sum (on Linux) or any Windows MD5sum utility (looks like http://www.md5summer.org has a decent one, or just [google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+md5sum)).