# How to flash the gapps package after installing CyanogenMod

Tags: cyanogenmod, custom-roms

I have recently installed the `CyanogenMod` in my Samsung N700.
Issues now i want to install Google apps like play store, maps etc. Learning from [here](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/74512-where-is-my-google-account-stuff-why-does-play-store-crash/) i have download the `.zip` package and it is in my sdcard now.

Issue is now i don't know how to use it, if i try to open it its says no application to handle such(zip) files.

Can anyone please guide me through this?

Answer (score 14):

The Gapps zip file is in the same format as the CyanogenMod ROM, and as such needs to be installed in a similar way. However, unlike the ROM installation, Installing Gapps won't remove anything (other than currently installed Gapps, if any) from your phone.

You need to boot into your Recovery (Based on [your previous question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/55328/corrupt-rom-file-at-cyanogenmod-server), this will be ClockWorkMod Recovery) and install that zip file in the same way you installed the ROM. **Booting into recovery mode will be easier now that you have CM installed**. I believe you should just be able to long-press the power button to get the reboot menu, and select "Recovery".

Edits may be helpful, but if I'm remembering CWM's process correctly, it'll be:

1. `Install from zip`
2. `Choose file`
3. (Find and select the gapps.zip file to install)

Also go to `Advanced` and clear your cache and dalvik cache afterward.

Comment: I have TWRP custom recovery instead. Does it matter?  I flash gapps the same time I flashed CyanogenMod, but gapps don't show.  Do I need to wipe the system first before reattempting (both), or can I just reattempt gapps only?

Comment: CM recovery is not suited for the task. Also, why do I need to clear dalvik cache afterwards? Will this remove my already installed app data, since I am updating CM?

Comment: @RahulParashar CWM Recovery is perfectly suited for this. TWRP is also a popular option. CM and CWM are not the same thing. The dalvik cache is only a cache; clearing it does not remove any data. You should clear it because it may still contain cache data that is incompatible with the newly installed Gapps. Whether or not your apps will be removed depends on whether you perform a Factory Reset while upgrading CyanogenMod.

Comment: Okay, I understand, good for avoiding bugs. 

Also, I am saying CM(CyanogenMod) not CWM, CM is not suited to flash Open-Gapps. I have encoutered errors, as in ERROR suggests to install using TWRP, after failing many times. Then, I went on and flashed CWM, after that I could install Gapps flawlessly.

Comment: @RahulParashar, you'll notice that I never suggested using CM to flash Gapps. Such a suggestion wouldn't even make sense.

Comment: Yes, That is what I am saying. Actually, we are both saying the same thing.

Comment: @RahulParashar Then why is your first comment, "CM recovery is not suited for the task."?

Comment: CM(CyanogenMod) is not suited for the task of flashing open-gapps. Isn't it correct?